# Strange issue with Symfony2 form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

When I reload page I get `true` as result of method call `isSubmited()`.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    var_dump($form->getData());
    die;
}
```

And output is:

> ...["submit"]=> NULL...

What should be the problem here?

On page load, form should not be submitted.

Comment: Form is being submitted while executing `handleRequest`.

Comment: If you reload a page that was requested with the POST method in your browser, it will resubmit the original form (although it should ask you for confirmation first). Maybe that is the reason of your confustion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if request is POST:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        var_dump($form->getData());
        die;
    }
}
```

Submitting a form in Symfony's view is binding data to it, which you did by `$form->handleRequest($request);` if request is a POST.

Comment: Hmm I now see, problem is because I send POST request (!?) on load page. I saying that because your example has give me true value, and when I tried with GET I had receive false value.

Comment: This is incorrect or at the very least not very useful. Form::handleRequest() will only submit if the method was POST to start with (unless otherwise configured).

Comment: @Gerry this is the case, I improved the answer.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that $form->isSubmitted() will always return false if the request was GET (unless otherwise configured in the form). Hence checking the request method is completely unnecessary. In fact, technically the only check required is $form->isValid(), which will also return false if the form was not submitted.

Answer (score 1):

The **handleRequest** method grabs the POST’ed data from the request, processes it, and
runs any validation. And actually, it only does this for POST requests so on a GET
request, **$form->isSubmitted()** returns false.

Tip: If you have a form that’s submitted via a different HTTP method, set them method.

For more details:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#method